# An issue with fieldset

Tags: html

I have used fieldset tag in HTML page, whereby i need some text to appear inside a box with legend tag as Text1. The issue is that in firefox, the corners of the box get rounded, but in IE the box that appears is a rectangular one. I need the box to have rounded corners . Please suggest some thing in this regard.

Comment: this could help:http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/html_table_tutorial_rounded_corners.php3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you say is the other way: IN IE it displays as a rectangle with rounded edges, and is the other way in Firefox.

Moreover, in "Classic" mode (Appearance Properties) Windows XP, the box has rectangular edges even in IE, and in "Windows XP mode" it has rounded edges.

If you *always* need a box with rounded corners, its better you *create a box with rounded corners* rather than using a fieldset. See comment from jjj or [this](http://www.google.com/search?&q=rounded+corners+html)

Comment: so do u mean that there is no way that i can get the fieldset box to be rounded??

Comment: I say that different browsers tend to render the fieldset in different ways... so if you *really* want rounded edges, better create one yourself... its not that difficult.
(See also http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum83/8234.htm)